# How can I represent a boolean type as it's relative integer?

Tags: java

I am practicing my Java and working on a program that will sum up all of the integers from `1` to `999` that are either a multiple of `3` or a multiple of `5`.

Here is what I've written so far:

```
public class MultiplesOfThreeAndFive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //For a number to be a multiple, i % number equals 0.
        MultiplesOfThreeAndFive m = new MultiplesOfThreeAndFive();
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++){
            System.out.println(m.checkIfMult(i));
        }
    }

    public boolean checkIfMult(int i){
        return (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0);
    }
}
```

Now when I compile this, all I get is true and false for each number from 1 to 999. I understand that this is because my method return type for my `checkIfMult` method is `boolean`.

I can't sum up true and false so I want to only acquire those numbers that display as true in the list.

EDIT:

Going by what Tom said...I added this to my main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //For a number to be a multiple, i % number equals 0.
    MultiplesOfThreeAndFive m = new MultiplesOfThreeAndFive();
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++){
        System.out.println(m.checkIfMult(i));
        if (m.checkIfMult(i) == true){    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So how about using a `sum` variable and an `if (checkIfMult)` check? This is no magic.

Comment: @Tom I don't understand how this would work if I can't sum up true and false.

Comment: You're not going to sum up `true` or `false`, you sum up `i` if your method returns `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a running sum like this:

```
public class MultiplesOfThreeAndFive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //For a number to be a multiple, i % number equals 0.
        MultiplesOfThreeAndFive m = new MultiplesOfThreeAndFive();

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++){
            if (m.checkIfMult(i))
            {
                sum = sum + i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
    }

    public boolean checkIfMult(int i){
        return (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0);
    }
}
```

**Side Note**: You can make the `checkIfMult` method static in this example. If you do so, then you don't need to create an instance of the  `MultiplesOfThreeAndFive` class.

Comment: Works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What about my compact solution?

```
IntStream.range(0, 1000).filter(i -> i % 3== 0 || i % 5 == 0).sum();
```

For your idea, create `sum` variable and add the following piece of code in the `for` statement:

```
if (m.checkIfMult(i)) sum += i;
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this.

Comment: Definitely compact! I think the limits are inclusive and the OP wants to stop at 999.

Comment: Yes I want to stop at 999 since it is < 1000.

Comment: @nicomp, `range(int startInclusive, int endExclusive)`

Comment: It is an interessting idea, but compact isn't alway better. Especially if too much happens on a single line. Makes debugging harder. But since this is no criterion for SO, +1.